# Populate two arrays of random length, with random numbers, using a list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

As the title suggests, i want to populate two separate lists, each with it's own random length and content using a list comprehension, something along the lines of:

```
a, b = [random.randint(1,100), random.randint(1,100) for x in range(random.randrange(1,10))]
```

Can it be done in a single line? If so how would i go about it?

Thanks

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, but an explanation as to why would be more useful than a: "No you can't". Could you elaborate on why this shouldn't or can't be done?

Thanks man

Comment: As you said in your question, "i want to populate two __separate__ lists, [...]" (emph mine), so it's much more clear to _separate_ this into two statements (i.e. two lines). There is no benefit from having it on one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you want to repeat the same function twice instead of creating two arrays separately. So let's write a function `random_array`

Now, we can use `random.choice(range(int))` to select a random number, e.g.

```
>>> choice(range(10))
7
```

Alternatively, we can use `random.randint(0, 10)` too:

```
>>> random.randint(0, 10)
5
```

Then, we can randomly choose N no. of integers given a range using `random.sample`:

```
>>> n = 5
>>> random.sample(range(10), n)
[3, 2, 1, 9, 4]
```

So using `random.sample` and `random.choice`:

```
>>> from random import sample, choice
>>> def random_array(maxsize, maxint):
...     return sample(range(maxint), choice(range(maxsize)))
... 
>>> random_array(10, 100)
[12, 9, 62, 48, 11, 44, 58, 52, 1]
>>> random_array(10, 100)
[97, 78, 33, 3]
```

Or `random.randint` and `random.sample`:

```
>>> from random import randint, sample
>>> def random_array(maxsize, maxint):
...     return sample(range(maxint), randint(0, maxsize))
... 
>>> random_array(10, 100)
[27, 50, 95, 18, 4, 30, 73, 47]
```

Or using `numpy`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.rand() # Random float between 0.0 to 1.0
0.7796560918112618
>>> np.random.rand(2)
array([ 0.75680381,  0.20146147])
>>> np.random.rand(2) # Random array of size 1x2 (column X row)
array([ 0.81612505,  0.42277987])

>>> np.random.rand(random.randint(0, maxsize)) # Random size array of len < maxsize
array([ 0.83846215,  0.77637599,  0.85086381,  0.03674837])
>>> np.random.rand(random.randint(0, maxsize)) # Random size array of len < maxsize
array([ 0.26468399,  0.0472708 ,  0.83615985,  0.20740113,  0.40436625,
        0.84332336,  0.48814732,  0.39267764,  0.30662132])
>>> np.random.rand(random.randint(0, maxsize)) * 100 # Random size array of len < maxsize and max value < 100
array([ 80.85771169,  50.49196633,  21.01646636,  36.15074652,
        97.98209728,  85.68512275,  58.06013557,  23.93219465,
         5.18467685,  12.77761391])
```

---

If you want a single liner:

```
a =  sample(range(100), choice(range(10)))
```

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, but if i really wanted to do it in a single line, would it be ok to do it like this 

`a, b = [random.randint(1,100) for x in range(random.randrange(1,10))], [random.randint(1,100) for x in range(random.randrange(1,10))]`?

Comment: Why don't you want a function? You can generate infinite no. of arrays without hardcoding =)

Comment: Because this isn't for practical use. I'm just doing some basic python exercises and wanted to make it as short as i could.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to different lists created in one line, then you are referring to a nested list:

```
import random

l = [[random.randint(1, 100) for b in range(random.randint(1, 100))] for i in range(2)]
```

However, if you just want two separate lists, then it will take two lines:

```
l1 = [random.randint(1, 100) for b in range(random.randint(1, 100))]

l2 = [random.randint(1, 100) for b in range(random.randint(1, 100))]
```

Comment: I think  you are close. It can just be `a,b = [[random.randint(1, 100) for b in range(random.randint(1, 100))] for i in range(2)]`

Answer (score 0):

Made it works this way

```
a, b = [random.randint(1,100) for x in range(random.randrange(1,10))], [random.randint(1,100) for x in range(random.randrange(1,10))]
```

According to some of the comments above, this probably isn't a good idea. Anyone care to explain exactly why that is?

Comment: readability is much more important than things going in less space. If i wanted  i could write entire programs on one liners - https://onelinepy.herokuapp.com/

Comment: You are asking why this isn't a good idea. Because it's much more difficult to read. You are trying to do two separate things so they really should go to separate lines. Also this blows up the length of the line, again making it more difficult to read (by the way [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) suggests a maximum line length of 79). There's no drawback in having two lines so it's rather the other way round, you should justify why to put this into one line. An advantage of short lines comes when comparing two versions with your VCS next to each other.

Comment: As @JoshuaNixon mentioned about readability, it is harder to debug lengthy lines.